# Can I get help getting image of Celestial Body at RA 2.220 and Declination +15.59?

Tags: star

My mom had a star named for my dad who died a few years back.   I told her that I'd try to find an image of that star and send it to her.  My dad's Birthday was 3/31/1931 if that helps.  Would love some help with this.  Thanks so much, in advance.  :-)

Comment: The bad news is that any such star naming is entirely unofficial and carries no weight.

Comment: Star's have a scientific designation system. Nowadays, they are *usually* named in order of their discovery, along with their constellation. "Naming a star" is completely unofficial.

Comment: Star naming as well as buying land on the Moon and Mars are all cons. just a way to exploit the vulnerable or uninformed. I'm sorry that you mom was exploited in the way.

Answer (score 2):

I think your star is an 8th magnitude star in Aries: properly catalogued as HD 14610. It is an F5 white dwarf, a little larger and brighter than the sun, but about 300ly away, and too dim to see without a telescope.

It is located at RA 02h 22m 01s, dec +15* 59' 30''

An image from the sky surveys: http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/sim-id?Ident=HD++14610 (click on "Interactive Aladin-lite to get a wider view)

Others have touched on the unofficial nature of these "star naming" services, which some feel are fraudulent.  However if it makes your mum happy.

Comment: The four [diffraction spikes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffraction_spike) radiating from that star image are side effects of the telescope's internal structure.